# Looking for a GUI library for OpenGL, or tips for my own (MetroUI)

Tags: opengl, gui

I am making an OpenGL graphics accelerated FPS, and I need to find a library to handle GUI correctly. My current GUI handler just wont do!

Yes, as in the title says, the UI of the game is Metro (ZuneHD, WP7, etc).

So the UI contains little to NO images, just fonts.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question because first you say you need a GUI library but then you say the game uses this Metro for UI. Also, your references to Zune and Windows Phone implies to me you need something in C# for XNA but you didn't actually specify that.

Comment: @jhocking Sorry for the confusion. I need a GUI library that can imitate the features of Zune and WP7. It will be C++ OpenGL.So like, Text with very little bitmaps. If that isn't availabe, I dont mind making my own, I just need some tips if that is the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good GUI for OpenGL](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/good-gui-for-opengl)

Comment: on sourceforge, tiny file dialogs has several modal function calls. it's a simple C C++ cross-platform file to add to your project.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best GUI libraries that renders in OpenGL is CEGUI:
http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

It isn't specifically designed to emulate WP7 but I would imagine you can accomplish that with customized graphics within CEGUI.

Comment: I know it's free and open-source, but blimey, it looks *so* cruddy.  Just a default style would be great - looks like this project is dying for a designer for an hour or two

Comment: The lack of professionalism isn't just because it's open-source; the CE stands for "Crazy Eddie's." A better default look would be nice, but it can be skinned.

Comment: http://sfloyd.wmclan.net/hue/galleries/jing/2011-04-10_1404.png    This is what I am going for, very minimal, text based, and shape based GUI.