# Responsive GUI with Unity and C# script

Tags: unity, gui, menu

I'm working on my character menu for an RPG in Unity. I have my menu set up with different buttons for different categories. All is well, except when I re-size my screen, my layout is sized incorrectly. I need my GUI to respond to my screen size. Is there any information or a tutorial I can read?

Comment: @JohnMcDonald I'm not sure I agree with your edit.  Responsive is the term used to describe web layouts that react to screen size changes, and I think it's appropriate for a game GUI too.  I don't agree that there could be confusion about how quickly a GUI reacts to input (for any non-terrible GUI, anyway).  I would recommend a rollback.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Although you don't know where to begin searching, you are essentially asking for a tutorial on this subject.  That's outside the guidelines of what should be asked on this site, which is why I voted to close it.  But, [here is a question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24103/immediate-gui-yae-or-nay) that ought to get you pointed in the right direction.  Good luck in your research!

Comment: Quite a lot to read... Thanks @SethBattin. Also, responsive is exactly what I meant. My GUI system is actually based on a pseudomorphic Tablet Application. What I mean is, my GUI is created as my player plays an animation of taking a tablet out and turning it on. The GUI is just an app.

Comment: @SethBattin, rolled back. I did not recognize it as a common term in the web world.

Comment: What are you currently doing?  Are you using UnityGUI or some other middleware?

Comment: Currently I'm scripting my GUI in C# script. I'm working on a scale ratio method where the GUI is set up from a reference resolution and then the actual resolution is compared and the resulting ratio is multiplied to the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm disturbing an old thread but I feel it's worth it. You can use the all new unity 4.6 with a great UI system. The anchors is the magic word you should look for.
Setting the anchors of the UI elements to their corners will make them responsive. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue. I accomplished this by creating a ratio based on target screen sizes and actual screen sizes. This ratio is then applied to static value coordinates.